# About authorization in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a permission based Authorization for Asp.net Core while I am moving to core from .net framework. I built an Authorization system based on my needs(using Identity). Basically I am adding Claims to Roles and Users have roles. I built checkboxes for assigning roles to user and assigning claims to roles. Everything works well but here is my question:

While the system is working, let's say user1 has "Admin Role". user1 can access the pages based on the policies which are using his roles->claims. The problem starts here. While user1 is logged in, if I change the claims of "Admin" role, user1 won't be effected until he/she log off and login again.

Anyone has an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're generating a token when the user logs in that contains the roles and/or claims for that user at the instant that they logged in, so you'd need to regenerate that token (log them in again, if that makes more sense) and send it back to the user. If you're using cookies, this shouldn't be too hard (you can log-in an already logged-in user without their password)

Comment: Actually I didn't add anything new on Asp.net Core identity system. With .net framework I was using sessions and custom authorize class to handle the sessions. With core, I wanted to try personal accounts authentication while building the project(Built in). I derived ApplicationUser from Identity user. I only coded pages to add claims to roles and add roles to users(using UserManager and RoleManager). And I added policies on startup.cs. Honestly I have no idea how authorization works. Here is my repository link. I would be appreciated if you teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to work... but let me raise up a caution a bit...

- Performance issue

Since you have to check the permission on database for every client request (which will have a real burden to the system). I know it seems like you're building classic mono app. But the server will still suffer from coming back and forth database hard.

- The user doesn't know what's happening.

Imagine you display a report section that user usually access it frequently, but on some nice day... the browser blank out, or pop-up some dialog that she doesn't have permission to using this anymore. That's could cause real issue cause user only use what they need at the very moment. What'll happen if it's 10 minutes to the meeting and an assistance needed to print out some report and that pop-up ? (from my experienced lesson (XD)).

So I highly suggest that, on app deployemnt and user login, take all their role and claims from database once and cache them somewhere (like `IMemoryCache`, since we are targeting classic mono app), then check the claim on caches afterward.

Everytime user permission changed, update the cache, and log the user out right at that moment. If something bad happen. User would yelling at the person who setting the permission, not us as developers.

Seems like you have spend a few continuously hours to complete your own decent solution since last time.

Good work mate

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly I was just thinking about the performance issue. I don't know how to use cache and IMemoryStore, I will take a look on these topics. Thanks again, have a nice day!

Comment: Mah bad... sorry... it's the [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), not `IMemoryStore`... I fixed the answer too... thanks to mention that (XD)

Comment: btw could you fix your VS Code problem? I searched but couldn't find any good extensions for that

Comment: Unfortunately i doesn't know how. But sInce I work on both reactjs and .net core, across windows, Ubuntu(i guess mac would be the same). I bet you'll really happy using [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) for .net things, and VsCode for others. My life relief a lot since then.

Comment: I did a quick search and came up with some ideas. If we use IMemoryCache, seems like it's a good solution for small apps. But what happens if the traffic is high? I mean IMemoryCache is using server ram right? And if we think to store claims on cookies to prevent high ram usage, this time it will create a security breach since users may change the cookie values. Hmmm and it's a shame who downvoted this question, I guess it was a pretty lit question

Comment: Since we target classic mono app, i don't think it could grow quite big, like 3-500CCU would be plenty. And you absolutely can use Cookie for storing those. But remember, nothing safe on clients. And if you target to look at some horizontal scalling system, like microservices design, i suggest to take a look at redis. I use them all the time, this [library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.redis.rediscache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2) should be plenty enough for 80% common usecases

Comment: Learnt a lot from you, thank you for everything. It's my time to start learning these now. Thanks again and have a nice day! Hope we'll meet again ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I came up with a solution.

```
internal class PermissionAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
{
    UserManager<User> _userManager;
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public PermissionAuthorizationHandler(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.Name == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get all the roles the user belongs to and check if any of the roles has the permission required
        // for the authorization to succeed.
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
        var userRoleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        var userRoles = _roleManager.Roles.Where(x => userRoleNames.Contains(x.Name));

        foreach (var role in userRoles)
        {
            var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            var permissions = roleClaims.Where(x => x.Type == CustomClaimTypes.Permission &&
                                                    x.Value == requirement.Permission)
                                        .Select(x => x.Value);

            if (permissions.Any())
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then we call this in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();
```

For more detailed answer please check: https://www.zehntec.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/